# Replace \n with '' by using str_replace() in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following code

```
$s = '\n test@gmail.com \n ';
$s = str_replace('\n', '', $s);

echo $s;
```

I want to replace the `'\n'` char with `''` but it's not working with the above code. I have found that as `\n` is the new line char with ascii value 10 by `echo ord(substr($s, 0, 1));` it is not working. It's not clear to me what is the exact reason behind not working the above code. please help.

Comment: Use double quote : "\n" instead or escape the \

Comment: Check out http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php - it explains the different ways strings can be specified in PHP. Also `trim()` might be the function you're after instead of `str_replace()`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to place the \n in **double** quotes.
Inside single quotes it is treated as 2 characters '\' followed by 'n'

Try below code:

```
$s = "\n test@gmail.com \n";
$s = str_replace("\n", '', $s);

echo $s;
```

Comment: First line should also use double quotes - current code won't change the string at all.

Comment: yes there is typo , updated the answer thanks @steve

Answer (score 5):

You have to use double quotes. [\n is not interpreted as newline with single quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single).